# credit card implementation in Titanium

Tags: titanium-mobile

Now these days I am developing an app in titanium. Where i need to develop the code to use the Credit card payment from the App. i am done with paypal integration as it is available in Tianium as MPL.But I could not find any possibility of using the Credit card payment through the App as well as there is no module is available in Titanium so far as.
is there anybody had any experience such kind of Commerce app kindly share the Terms with me.I have very short Timelines for the Project.
I have seen an app **PHOTOEXPRESS** where we can use the Credit card payment processing. As I think this might be done by using WebView.
But I dont understand How to make the Connection with URL related to Credit card API.If anybody have any idea about this alternate way to go Kindly share.Any kind of help would be Appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Actually Titanium has an implementation of Mobile Commerce, take a look:

http://www.appcelerator.com/products/titaniumcommerce/

but if you want to do a manually implementation of PayPal for example, you can try this:

http://developer.appcelerator.com/question/117057/how-can-i-integrate-paypal-in-titanium

That will fix your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can try below mentioned modules for credit card payment-

[ZooZ](https://marketplace.appcelerator.com/apps/1170#!overview)

[clover](https://marketplace.appcelerator.com/apps/2186#!overview)